# How I should get all interactive and remote logon sessions from the remote computer

Tags: powershell, devops

My task: write a script to get all interactive and remote logon sessions for the selected remote computer. And for every session find associated user information.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param([string]$computername=$env:computername)


function get-logedonuser {            
    param ($computername)            
    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogonSession -ComputerName $computername |ForEach-Object {            
     $data = $_                   
     $id = $data.__RELPATH -replace """", "'"            
     $q = "ASSOCIATORS OF {$id} WHERE ResultClass = Win32_Account"            
     Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computername -Query $q |            
     Select-Object @{N="User";E={$($_.Caption)}},             
     @{N="LogonTime";E={$data.ConvertToDateTime($data.StartTime)}} 
     Get-WmiObject -Query "select * from win32_loggedonuser" | ForEach-Object { (($_.Antecedent -Split "Name=`"")[1] -Split "`"")[0] }            
    }            
}
```

How should I find all associated user information? Could you help me?

Comment: What does *'all associate user information'* actually mean?

Comment: Just need to output user name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use classes `Win32_LogonSession` and `Win32_Account`.